# Laravel 8: How to get errors flashed to session while in PHP (NOT blade template)

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I'm calling this:

```
request()->validate($rules);
```

If there is an error, then Laravel will flash the errors to the session and return to the previous page.

How do I get the errors that Laravel flashed to session from *within PHP*?

I am *not* referring to getting errors in a Blade template, or using a Blade template directive.

For example, how could I get errors if I was coding within a class file.

Comment: the template is PHP code ... but they errors are in the session, so where ever you can reach the session

Comment: @lagbox template is a superset of PHP code along with directives, template variables, etc. How do I retrieve the errors from the session?  Where do I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it

```
$viewErrorBag = session()->get('errors');
$bag = $viewErrorBag->getBag('default');
$errors = $bag->all()
```

Comment: `$viewErrorBag = session()->get('errors') ?: new \Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag;` if you wanted to make sure you always have a `ViewErrorBag` even if there are no errors set

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont really understand what you mean by getting the errors from within PHP code.

> Try This if it would help

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <strong><li>{{ $error }}</li></strong>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

> **Or Explain your question better if that doesnt help**

Comment: I was referring to code that's not in a Blade template file, thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code you are working on?...

Comment: I did edit it.  Can you tell me what is unclear about the question?    That is the code.

Comment: Oh ok I saw you were able to solve it Yourself.... Nice.....well i still need more reputation